# SEQUENCE GENRATE AUTO I NEVER SAVE THEM BUT EVERY TIME IT MAKE NEW NUMB

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I CREATE A SIMPLE SEQUENCE IN ORACLE 9I FORM 6I IN FORMS AT KEY-NEXT-ITEM TRIGER BUT I NEVER SAVE THAT BUT SEQUENCE STORE AUTO WHEN I OPEN NEW FORM IT MAKE NEW ENTRY I SEQUENCE IS

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CPV_SEQ
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
NOMAXVALUE
NOMINVALUE
NOCYCLE;
```

ON FORM LEVEL TRIGER AT KEY-NEXT-ITEM

```
SELECT CPV_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :VOUCHER_NO FROM DUAL ;
```

PLEASE HELP ME I WANT TO SAVE THAT CODE WHEN SAVE BUTTON PRESSED IF NOT THEN THAT DON'T SAVE THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Writing in ALL UPPERCASE is considered SHOUTING and rude. Please change this.

Comment: Don't become Shakespeare there is IT problem never asked English phrase

Comment: That has nothing to do with becoming Shakespeare. You are asking for (free) help - the least you can do is to be polite and show some courtesy

Answer (score 2):

Oracle sequences are never rolled back (unless you drop or alter it)  See the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) which states,

"When a sequence number is generated, **the sequence is incremented, independent of the transaction committing or rolling back**. If two users concurrently increment the same sequence, then the sequence numbers each user acquires may have gaps, because sequence numbers are being generated by the other user. One user can never acquire the sequence number generated by another user. After a sequence value is generated by one user, that user can continue to access that value regardless of whether the sequence is incremented by another user."

You should never have logic that depends on a sequence value being always incremented by 1 from a previous value.  There is no guarantee for that.